# How can I get more items in pop-up list of recent projects of Dock icon in VSCode?

Tags: dock, visual-studio-code

I currently have at most 10 recent items if I click on the VS Code icon in my Mac's Dock:

Is there a way to get more items?

[image]

Comment: Is it controlable in the preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idk whether this covers VS Code, I don't have it to check, but number of recents is a global pref in
System Preferences > General

[image]

Comment: Well, this setting works, but not in vscode. looks like vscode isn't really allow to support this.